# Create a polygon from a texture

Tags: geometry, game-engine, game-physics, computational-geometry

Let's say I've got a rgba texture, and a polygon class , which constructor takes vector array of verticies coordinates.
Is there some way to create a polygon of this texture, for example, using alpha channel of the texture ...? 
in 2d

Comment: This is a filling operation. When you fill the polygon, instead of assigning a constant color to the pixels, you fetch a  color value from the texture map, at the same coordinates. The way to implement that highly depends on the graphical framework that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, yes it can be done. Is it easy? No. I haven't seen any game/geometry engines that would help you out too much either. Doing it yourself, the biggest problem you're going to have is generating a simplified mesh. One quad per pixel is going to generate a lot of geometry very quickly. Holes in the geometry may be an issue if you're tracing the edges and triangulating afterwards. Then there's the issue of determining what's in and what's out. Alpha is the obvious candidate, but unless you're looking at either full-on or full-off, you may be thinking about nice smooth edges. That's going to be hard to get right and would probably involve some kind of marching squares over the interpolated alpha. So while it's not impossible, its a lot of work.

**Edit**: As pointed out below, Unity does provide a method of generating a polygon from the alpha of a sprite - a [PolygonCollider2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/430/Documentation/Components/class-PolygonCollider2D.html). In the [script reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/430/Documentation/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.html) for it, it mentions the `pathCount` variable which describes the number of polygons it contains, which in describes which indexes are valid for the `GetPath` method. So this method could be used to generate polygons from alpha. It does rely on using Unity however. But with the combination of the sprite alpha for controlling what is drawn, and the collider controlling intersections with other objects, it covers a lot of use cases. This doesn't mean it's appropriate for your application.

Comment: unity3d does that. when you add a collider to an object , it automatically generates its shape.